# Next.js 11 - Image optimization is not working on production environment

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, image, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a little issue with Image component in Next.js. I am using **next 11.0.1** version, and I did not find any problems during development and local environment. The images are being optimized and everything is working fine. However, team and I find out that the images are not being optimized when the site is deployed on production. We are using Amazon services to do that.

Here is the proof of what I mean by this:

##### Local environment:

```
On wide-screen (1024px width)
Rendered size:  50 x 50 px
File size:  1.3 kB
```

##### Production environment:

```
On wide-screen (1024px width)
Rendered size:  512 x 512 px
File size:  41.5 kB
```

Of course, this is not a huge difference, but still I want to know how to fix this issue on production environment. I also added **sharp** dependency on the project itself, as I know that it will boost the performance of loading the images on the page. Can the problem be with Amazon not being set up properly?

##### Next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['avatars.slack-edge.com'],
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you show your image component? I accidentally read the question wrong. Also, x10 is quite a big difference?

Answer (score 1):

Next.js image optimization requires sharp npm package as dependency. (https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/install-sharp)

Make sure the sharp npm package is properly installed on the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct legacy package for Next.js < v13 `next/legacy/image`?

"Starting with Next.js 13, the next/image component was rewritten to improve both the performance and developer experience. In order to provide a backwards compatible upgrade solution, the old next/image was renamed to next/legacy/image."

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/legacy/image

I'm not asking if you tested with the same device prod/dev, because you know that on smaller devices you get smaller images (image always optimized for target device)